# CustomDialog, modality and dispose on close

Tags: java, jdialog

I have a `CustomDialog` that extends `JDialog`.

In its `constructor` I have

```
setModalityType(ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);

setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

They dont seem to work well together: i think the Modality stucks the `defaultcloseoperation`, and in the end i have to click twice the `X` in order to get the `CustomDialog` closed.

How should i act to obtain both

1- always on-top visualization (i use `application_modal` for this)

2- dispose on close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer to provide people who have the same "click the X twice in order to close" behaviour a future reference.

My issue was related to a double setVisible(true), one in the constructor and one in a "initializer" function.

With only 1 setVisible(true), the issue is gone

Answer (score 2):

It works for me:

```
dialog.setModal(true);
dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

Comment: I have to click twice the X button in order to close the Jdialog. As far as i Click the first time, seems like nothing happens